# $\Im \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}$ where $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do I find
\begin{equation*}
\Im \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}} = \Im \frac{1}{1-e^{-(x+iy)}}?
\end{equation*}
I tried multiplying by $e^z/e^z$ and the very counter-productive approach: power series of $e^z$. I'm sure the result is something with hyperbolic sine and cosine. A hint would be much obliged. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}=\frac{e^z}{e^z-1}=\frac{e^z}{e^z-1}\frac{e^{\bar z}-1}{e^{\bar z}-1}=\frac{e^{2\Re z}-e^z}{|e^z-1|^2}$$

then

$$\Im\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}\right)=\frac1{|e^z-1|^2}\Im\left(-e^z\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach which uses Euler's formula: $e^{iy} = \cos y + i \sin y$ and so $e^{-z}+e^{-\overline{z}}=2e^{-x}\cdot \cos y$.
Then:
$$
\Im \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}} = \frac{i}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}-\frac{1}{1-e^{-\overline{z}}}\right)=\frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{z}-e^{-\overline{z}}}{1-e^{z}-e^{-\overline{z}}+e^{-2x}}=$$$$\frac{i}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{z}-e^{-\overline{z}}}{1-e^{z}-e^{-\overline{z}}+e^{-2x}}
= \frac{ e^{-x}\cdot \sin y}{1-2e^{-x}\cdot \cos y+e^{-2x}}$$

Comment: Isn't there is an "i" at the denominator missing in the first step?

Comment: It was an typos. Fixed. Thank you so much